# Import existing project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee-5

How do I import an existing project in eclipse (latest). I have downloaded a project from git repo. It is a legacy Java web application. Project directory structure:

```
Myapp
  -.settings
       .jsdtscope (added in my local)
       org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs (added in my local)
       org.eclipse.wst.common.component (added in my local)
       org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml (added in my local)
       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container (modified in local from repo contents)
       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container(modified in local from repo)
  -project
      settings
      .project (It is xml file with <projectDescription> <buildSpec>....)
  -src
     com.abc.xyz
         core
         model
         service
         util
  -testsrc
  -web
     html
     js
     jsp
     images
     WEB-INF
          classes
          application.xml
          applicationContext.xml
          web.xml
  -build.xml
```

I tried to import the project in Eclipse in various ways, and it's always imported incorrectly. For example, when import as:

1. Existing Project into workspace
2. File System
   For option 1 and 2 there is one src folder containing all the packages and code as expected, except core

   src
   com.abc.xyz
   model
   service
   util
   But, then there is another package created with src.com.abc.xyz.core (no idea why this is happening) due to which jsp pages are not able to find java classes in core
3. Projects from folder or archive - issue is web folder is not imported at all.

Please let me know is there any way to import this manually and run this on tomcat using Eclipse

Comment: _File > Open Projects from File System..._ is the recommended way to import projects. The project structure looks weird. Is `.settings` a file or folder (if it's a folder, is the folder empty)? What's the content of `project/.project` (an Eclipse project would have a `.project` in the root folder, not in a subfolder, and a Java project would also have a `.classpath` file which seems missing here too).

Comment: @howlger I have modified my question with .settings folder and .project contents available in repo when I import it. Also, when I import the project in my local it adds .project and .classpath in root.  When I get latest code from repo and On using File > Open Projects from File System, it just imports src folder and build.xml and the jars. The web folder is not imported at all. Can I add them manually in Java Build Path or add Deployment Assembly